# Vectorizing a dreadfully slow groupBy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which I've mostly vectorized but on some columns have needed to result to looping with groupBy. The speed is tolerable for a small dataset but becomes absurdly slow for anything larger than 50k+ rows.

The basic idea is that when the column `unique` has a value (`np.isfinite`), wait a number of days (4 in example) and set `complete` as `True`. Repeat. The positive results between the 4 periods (days) should be ignored.

This is what I have now, it's perfectly functional but horribly slow. I'm very interested in how I could vectorize this.

```
times = np.arange(datetime(2019, 11, 1), datetime(2019, 12, 1), timedelta(days=1)).astype(datetime)
times = np.concatenate([times, times])
names = np.array(['ALFA'] * 30 + ['BETA'] * 30)

unique = np.random.randn(60)
unique[unique < 0.7] = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'unique':unique, 'complete':np.nan}, index=[names, times])
df.index = df.index.set_names(['Name', 'Date'])

df['num'] = df.groupby('Name').cumcount()
entryNum, posit = len(df.index)+1, 0

for n, group in df.groupby(level=['Name']):
    posit = 0
    for date, col in group.groupby(level=['Date']):
        if col.num[0] - entryNum == 4:
            posit = 0
            df.loc[(n, date), 'complete'] = True
        if not posit and np.isfinite(col.unique[0]):
            posit = 1
            entryNum = col.num[0]
```

---

**rafaelc**'s solution is genius but there are differences in certain cases:

test set for `unique` column:

```
unique = [0.808154, np.nan, np.nan, 0.976455, np.nan, 1.81917, np.nan, 0.732306, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.878656, np.nan, 1.087899, 1.57941, 1.211292, np.nan, 1.431411, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.323002, 1.339211, np.nan, np.nan, 1.322755, np.nan, 0.960014, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.833514, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.3884, np.nan, np.nan, 1.372292, np.nan, np.nan]
```

output:

```
                   unique complete  countnonnull  solution
Name Date
ALFA 2019-11-01  0.808154      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-02       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-03       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-04  0.976455      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-05       NaN     True           1.0      True
     2019-11-06  1.819170      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-07       NaN      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-08  0.732306      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-09       NaN      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-10       NaN     True           1.0     False
     2019-11-11       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-12       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-13       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-14       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-15       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-16       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-17       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-18  0.878656      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-19       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-20  1.087899      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-21  1.579410      NaN           3.0     False
     2019-11-22  1.211292     True           3.0      True
     2019-11-23       NaN      NaN           3.0     False
     2019-11-24  1.431411      NaN           3.0     False
     2019-11-25       NaN      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-26       NaN     True           1.0     False
     2019-11-27       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-28       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-29       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-30       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
BETA 2019-11-01  1.323002      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-02  1.339211      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-03       NaN      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-04       NaN      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-05  1.322755     True           2.0      True
     2019-11-06       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-07  0.960014      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-08       NaN      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-09       NaN     True           1.0     False
     2019-11-10       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-11       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-12       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-13       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-14  1.833514      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-15       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-16       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-17       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-18       NaN     True           0.0      True
     2019-11-19       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-20       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-21       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-22       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-23       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-24       NaN      NaN           0.0     False
     2019-11-25  2.388400      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-26       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-27       NaN      NaN           1.0     False
     2019-11-28  1.372292      NaN           2.0     False
     2019-11-29       NaN     True           1.0      True
     2019-11-30       NaN      NaN           NaN     False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach, only groupby once:

```
def update(v, thresh=4):
    ret = v.copy()
    count = 5
    for i in ret.index:
        count += 1
        if ret.loc[i]:
            if count >= 4:
                count = 0
            else:
                ret.loc[i] = np.nan
    return ret

groups = df.groupby('Name')
df['f_complete'] = groups['unique'].shift(4).notnull()
df['f_complete']= groups['f_complete'].apply(update)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm seeing the correct output but I'm hesitant to use looping. I'll try timing on a large dataset later.

Comment: Like I comment at rafael's answer, this kind of dynamic does need sequential, i.e. looping. Using `apply` allows vectorization across the `Name`, but within each `Name`, I'm afraid you don't have much choice.

Comment: Incredibly, despite looping on a 22k row set, it's even about 2-3% faster than the vectorized approach and a whole magnitude faster than the original. The difference with mine only increases (non-linearly). Unexpected!

Comment: What vectorized approach? Also, looping once over 50k rows isn’t as bad as it sounds.

Comment: The one by rafaelc. I'm still looking for additional speed gains and if numba could be applied somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Let's play with `shift`. My output `solution` below will have `False` and `True` values, but you can easily map the values back to `NaN` to *exactly* match your expectaction, but that's just a detail.

```
g = df.groupby(level=0)['unique']

df['countnonnull'] = (pd.DataFrame({f'shift_{i}': g.shift(i) for i in range(1,5)})
                        .notnull()
                        .sum(1)
                        .shift(-1))

df['solution'] = (df['unique'].where(df['countnonnull'].eq(1))
                              .groupby(level=0)
                              .shift(4)
                              .notnull())
```

```
                   unique expected  solution
Name Date                                   
ALFA 2019-11-01  1.624345      NaN     False
     2019-11-02       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-03       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-04       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-05  0.865408     True      True
     2019-11-06       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-07  1.744812      NaN     False
     2019-11-08       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-09       NaN     True      True
     2019-11-10       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-11  1.462108      NaN     False
     2019-11-12       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-13       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-14       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-15  1.133769     True      True
     2019-11-16       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-17       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-18       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-19       NaN     True      True
     2019-11-20       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-21       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-22  1.144724      NaN     False
     2019-11-23  0.901591      NaN     False
     2019-11-24       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-25  0.900856      NaN     False
     2019-11-26       NaN     True      True
     2019-11-27       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-28       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-29       NaN      NaN     False
     2019-11-30       NaN      NaN     False
```

Comment: Your solution indeed gives the correct output. I'm still under the impression that the cumulative thresholding like this cannot be vectorized and must be done in sequential fashion. I'm must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: Awesome but it doesn't return True in certain cases. If you run the example multiple times, you should encounter the difference.

Comment: @misantroop interesting. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yea, that was my impression too. Well, I "bypassed" the need for loops by creating shifted columns (in this case `N = 4`) which means possibly huge memory consumption..

Comment: @rafael try your solution with all `1` in `unique`.

Comment: @rafaelc added an example.

Comment: Will take a look as soon as I can!